# Does Windows 7 treat full-screen applications differently?

Tags: winapi, windows-7, fullscreen, execution

I have a hidden process that waits for non-standard hardware button messages and runs an application (with CreateProcess). No problem with the user disturbing, it's an action that the user approved himself. Everything is fine when it's usual layout with taskbar shown and multiply captioned and non captioned- windows. But the situation is different in XP and 7, when the current application is full-screen. Full-screen application in this case is window without borders having exactly the same dimension as the screen. Windows hides taskbar for such application even if it's always on.

In Xp, it's ok, the taskbar is being shown in this case and appication (for example calculator) also, the full-screen app is still visible in areas other than the launched app's and taskbar'. But in Windows 7 nothing visual happens, the full-screen app is still on and if I switch to taskbar, the executed application is there. I tried to solve it with SetForegroundWindow, BringWindowToTop, even AllowSetForegroundWindow(GetCurrentProcessId()) call for a window handle found with CreateProcess-WaitForIntputIdle-EnumThreadWindows, no change. So did something change since XP related to full-screen windows that officially documented?

Thanks,

Max

Comment: When you tried `SetForegroundWindow`, did you also check the error code? (BTW, `AllowSetForegroundWindow(GetCurrentProcessId())` is meaningless. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/20/9435239.aspx )

Answer (score 1):

Vista introduced the [desktop composition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/dwm-overview) feature. In short, all windows are drawing to a memory bitmaps and the Desktop Window Manager is then composing these bitmaps and drawing on a full-screen Direct3D surface. Full-screen windows do not participate in the desktop composition and get to draw directly on the screen (mostly because the majority of full-screen apps are games that need real-time screen updates).

In particular, this means that when a full screen app is up and running, it is covering the DWM composed image and the user needs to switch to a DWM-managed window for the DWM to start drawing on top of the full-screen app.

I don't have a good solution for your problem, unfortunately. One way to solve it would be to add the WS_CAPTION style to your app and then handle `WM_NCPAINT`/`WM_NCCALCSIZE`/`WM_NCHITTEST` yourself. This would allow you to lie to the DWM that you are a regular windowed application, but change visually your NC area to look like you have no title. However, this does require certain amount of additional code and might be a bit more effort you want to invest.

Another way you can try to solve your problem is to explicitly minimize your full-screen application window when launching the new process. However, you will then have to solve the problem of when to maximize it back again.

Btw, you might find the comments on [this post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100412-00/?p=14353) from Raymond Chen interesting.

Comment: From my understanding, desktop composition would/should not have an influence on calls to `SetForegroundWindow`, `BringWindowToTop` and the like.

Comment: I believe `SetForegroundWindow` is prevented from interrupting full-screen applications to prevent background processes from popping over games. `BringWindowToTop` manipulates the Z-order and full-screen apps don't participate in the normal z-order (or were set as topmost when active - don't remember exactly)

Comment: Then again, I haven't looked into this for couple of years, so I might have forgotten everything I ever knew. :-)

Comment: Thanks for this variant. But is the application that does not change display resolution, but only follow the rules in order for taskbar to dissappear, still can be considered full-screen and appliable to DWM manager?

Comment: If an applications has no non-client area and covers the desktop, it is considered a full-screen app.

Comment: `SetForegroundWindow` generally is prevented when it's not in response to user input. (See the post from Raymond Chen that I linked to.) It does raise the question about what criteria the window manager uses to identify user input and whether Maksee's non-standard hardware button messages qualify. (I'm not familiar with desktop composition stuff, but it seems like the general rule should be sufficient without needing special ones for full screen windows.)

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that, if you have your own hardware device, that there is some API for generating "real" user input. Clearly the legacy keyboard and mouse, and now USB HID drivers (many of which are usermode I think?) have access to an API to do so.

Synergy+ for example can generate fake keyboard and mouse events on connected PCs, and the consequence of the faked input is windows switching activation normally.

So, my initial idea is for your usermode "Device" application to synthesize actual keyboard messages - SendInput seems a likely candidate for "the API that can "fake" real user input events.

Then, use an API like RegisterHotKey in your "UI" app to respond to the hotkey combination your device app generates.

Now, (assuming that SendInput IS generating user input events at the correct level), you should (from within the WM_HOTKEY handler in your UI app) have permission (because everything was "user initiated") to change the foreground window (to yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Windows supports multiple [desktops](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682573%28VS.85%29.aspx) and my guess would be that the full screen up is using a different desktop than the default one (where your application will be shown). A desktop object in Windows is "a logical display surface and contains user interface objects such as windows, menus, and hooks". For example, screen savers normally are started on a separate desktop.

You can find out which desktop an application is running on using Process Explorer:

- Set Process Explorer to replace Task Manager and to run always on top.
- When your full screen up is shown, launch Process Explorer by pressing Ctrl + Shift + Esc
- Within Process Explorer, select the full screen process and press Ctrl + H to display the handles of this process
- See the value of the *Desktop* item in the list. Usually this would be set to *Default*

If you know what desktop this app is running on you can start your process on the same desktop by first calling [`OpenDesktop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684303%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get a handle to this desktop and then pass it into the [`STARTUPINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331%28VS.85%29.aspx) of your [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx) call.

Comment: By default, full screen apps use the same desktop as any other apps.

Comment: @Franci Penov: True, but who says that the app in question does? It is just a guess, of course, but worth mentioning that in this case the process started with `CreateProcess` won't be visible and you would see the exact same symptoms as described by the OP.

Comment: You are right this is a possibility. However, running on a separate desktop is quite uncommon scenario, so I'd think the OP would've explicitly mentioned it.

Comment: @France Penov: It is not uncommon, screen savers, kiosk applications, etc.. usually do run on their own desktop. And most developers are not aware that there is the possibility to have multiple desktops.